# jQuery $(document).ready broken in Iron/Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, document-ready

I've written a little image slideshow using jQuery and jFancyTiles which can be seen here:

http://www.netzwerkag.at

It works as expected in firefox and IE, but not in iron/chrome.The problem seems to be in the timing of document.ready in chromium:

- In line 76 the active class is set to the numbered circle-buttons in the lower right corner of the header image. This works!
- In line 83 the image is changed by calling the fancy-tile-function, this doesn't work in chromium, at least not at this time.

When i open the iron_js_console via ctrl-shift-j and manually call the function everything works.

Additionally, if i wait 10 seconds it even progresses to the next image, in all browsers, no previous action needed.

The first call to fancytiles does not work in iron/chrome. This is called on jquery's document.ready event.

//What can I do?

Comment: jQuery's `document.ready` can be triggered before some elements (images among them) are fully loaded. It is a wild guess, but have you tried using `$(window).load`?

Comment: didn't try - i'll immediately give it a shot... my guess is that chromium got a problem working with unloaded images. and if i break the JS-execution via an alert before the fancy-call the image in the bg is not loaded...

Comment: You could also try `$(document).bind("ready", function() { ... })` as I believe this is the last of the document load events to be fired.

Comment: thank you AJ and Rory... AJ's suggestion with $(window).load works, the bind to "ready" does not... if you write an answer AJ i'd luv to accept it :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue with both FF4 and Chrome. [`jQuery(document).ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) wasn't working. I was able to get it working with [`jQuery(window).load`](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). I'm not sure what changed in FF4, but they seemed to have made it more similar to how Chrome does things. When I changed it to use `jQuery(window).load`, it also cleared up issues I was having in Chrome.

Comment: i'd really love to accept an answer from AJweb - if he doesnt post one i'll accept your's - but he seems to need the rep more than you (1k vs 11k...)

Comment: @santa Oops, I didn't see his comment. I will delete my answer if he posts :)

Comment: i feel sorry for him - but answers have to be accepted this days :-)