# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL for Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

**toggle.js**

```
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
$jq(document).ready(function(){

    $jq('.isAdd').hide();

    $jq("#Add_category").change(function(){          
        var value = $jq("#Add_category option:checked").val();
        var theDiv = $jq(".isAdd");

        theDiv.slideToggle("slow");
    });
});​
```

In console I had:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

For Firefox it's works fine, but not for Chrome and Chromium for Ubuntu.

Comment: what is the HTML markup?

Comment: Here it is: http://pastie.org/2693372

Comment: On what line is the error thrown?

Comment: Btw the above code works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/ENxyL/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No visible cause for "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719859/no-visible-cause-for-unexpected-token-illegal)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an invisible character following the last `});` of your last line.  When I pasted it into my editor, it appeared as a `.`.

View your code in an editor capable of displaying non-printable characters with some kind of symbol, or view it in a hex editor.

Comment: Thanks, I copied and pasted so I'm assuming I copied an invisible character. After rewriting the code. It worked.

Comment: You can also get this error when you paste in code with double quotes that are curly rather than straight.

Comment: very useful tip! completely solve the problem on Chrome

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the solution to problem with "Unexpected Token ILLEGAL":

ILLEGAL means strictly Syntax Error.

**The Fix**

Install HxD Editor (recommended) and open your file in it. You can detect where exactly the error is occuring by detecting unusual `.` (as it happened with me), with the code's HEX representation. Save and replace the file.

Answer (score -1):

> @TiSer: please check your code for invisible white space chars, on
> document ready handler is not the problem here, it was the illegal
> token direct after them –  **Irishka Oct 14 '11 at 13:57**
>
> yeap, it's right! Incredible - one small symbol and all JS code fell.
> :) –  **TiSer Oct 17 '11 at 8:50**

$jq(document).ready(...); is causing this error Chrome

move your jQuery script to the bottom before < /body > tag

EDIT: check for white spaces

Comment: i can give you some links to read: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/solved-problem-in-chrome-document-ready , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596904/jquery-document-ready-problem-with-iron-chrome

Comment: `Unexpected token ILLEGAL` errors are caused by invalid syntax. The mere usage of a a ready handler cannot trigger such an error.

Comment: remove the ready event handler and error is gone, (replace change handler with delegate on the parent)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4264/discussion-between-irishka-and-sime-vidas)

Comment: @TiSer: please check your code for invisible white space chars,      on document ready handler is not the problem here, it was the illegal token direct after them

Comment: yeap, it's right! Incredible - one small symbol and all JS code fell. :)