# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

This code is working fine outside wordpress but Wordpress shows follwing error and does nothing. Can anyone tell the reason?
Thanks

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
>   custom_params.js:2Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method
>   'prettyPhoto'
>   chrome-extension://mpcddcfoblbgmnaklcpkbfajnfikinhn/videodownload.js:5Uncaught
>   TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
>   3/wordpress/?page_id=458:169Uncaught ReferenceError: addInput is not
>   defined

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var counter = 1;
var limit = 3;
function addInput(divName){
     if (counter == limit)  {
          alert("You have reached the limit of adding " + counter + " inputs");
     }
     else {
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
          counter++;
     }
}
</script>
<form method="POST">
     <div id="dynamicInput">
          Entry 1<br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>
     </div>
     <input type='button' value='Add another text input' onClick='addInput("dynamicInput")'>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

is caused by illegal characters/symbol. Usually its a invisible characters at the **end of line**. Try check `custom_params.js` line 2 for the invalid character.

This post has a good example:
[Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL for Chrome Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764035/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-illegal-for-chrome-browser)

Copy paste the code snippets there into notepad, you'll see an extra "?" character at the end of the snippet code.